# @commitlint/prompt-cli configuration not working

Tags: commitlint

I'm trying to configure my commitlint prompt to show a list for type selection.

This is my config file (commitlint.config.js):

```
module.exports = {
    extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],

    prompt: {
        questions: {
            type: {
                description: "My description:",
                enum: {
                    feat: {
                        description: 'A new feature',
                        title: 'Features',
                      },
                      fix: {
                        description: 'A bug fix',
                        title: 'Bug Fixes',
                      },
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

but is not working:
[prompt type question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvKzf.png)